# Which property should be applied here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having a problem with the following question:

> > If $$N = 3^P {  } $$ and $$M=P-1$$ Then in terms of M what is $$ \frac{3}{N}=?$$

Any suggestions on which properties to apply ?

Comment: Note that $\dfrac{3}{N}=\dfrac{3}{3^P}=\dfrac{1}{3^{P-1}}$. Or else more simply use $P=M+1$, so $3^P=3^{M+1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply substitute and use exponents' laws:
$$N=3^P\,,\,M=P-1\Longrightarrow \frac{3}{N}=\frac{3}{3^P}=\frac{1}{3^{P-1}}=\frac{1}{3^M}$$